# I want to show alert and redirect to another page using window.location.href in codeigniter controller

Tags: php

Below is my code in controller.

```php
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Already Rated!')
        window.location.href='http://localhost/Surecash_back/index.php/spa-details/Pune/1';
    </SCRIPT>");  
}
```

Alert is showing and page is also redirecting but in http://localhost/Surecash_back/index.php/spa-details/Pune/1' where "*Pune*" and "*1*" are static parameters and i want to pass dynamic parameters.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variables dynamically here

```
//set your variables dynamically here
  $area="pune";
  $index="1";
```

And set them in action here in this way..

```
if($query->num_rows() >0 ){
 $area="pune";
 $index="1";

    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
          window.alert('Already Rated!')
          window.location.href='http://localhost/Surecash_back/index.php/spa-details/$area/$index';
          </SCRIPT>");  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set route in your route file.

$route['controller_name/(:any)'] = 'controller_name/about/$1';

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I think it is really as simple as,

```
<?php
$VARIABLE_PRUNE = 'Prune';
$VARIABLE_ONE = 1;

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Already Rated!')
    window.location.href='http://localhost/Surecash_back/index.php/spa-details/" . $VARIABLE_PRUNE . "/" . $VARIABLE_ONE . "';
</SCRIPT>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!!I Its working...actually i was using (+)instead of (.)

Comment: The character for concatenation in PHP is `.` so just remember that :) If my answer helped, feel free to mark it as correct?